# Bind WAN to TD-W8960N

Tags: networking, local-area-network, adsl, tp-link

I have a TD-W8960N DSL modem. It is possible to have multiple WAN services on the device as in[image: Multiple WAN service]

Both of them are doing great as in Diagnostic
[image: Diagnostic pass]

How is it possible to bind two different computer to each of them ? (The result should gave two different public IP address on each system)

**Update**

Someone told me that it's called multi PVC